# Glossary entry not updated

Tags: glossaries

I am testing the use of a list of symbols using the `\newglossaryentry` using Texmaker (4.4.1). However, I am experiencing some problems.

Using the following example I create glossary entries:

```
\documentclass{article}

% Load the package
\usepackage{glossaries}

% Generate the glossary
\makeglossaries

\begin{document}

%Term definitions
\newglossaryentry{ta}{name=Test1, description={Test1}}
\newglossaryentry{tb}{name=Test2, description={Test2}}
\newglossaryentry{tc}{name=Test3, description={Test3}}

% Use the terms
\gls{ta} is three hours behind \gls{tb} and 10 hours ahead of \gls{tc}.

%Print the glossary
\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

If I initially generate the document using:

1. pdflatex
2. makeglossaries
3. pdflatex

The glossary is printed just the way I have entered it. However, if I change a description and reprocess (`pdflatex`,`makeglossaries` and `pdflatex`)  the document nothing changes:

```
\documentclass{article}

% Load the package
\usepackage{glossaries}

% Generate the glossary
\makeglossaries

\begin{document}

%Term definitions
\newglossaryentry{ta}{name=Test1, description={Test123}}
\newglossaryentry{tb}{name=Test2, description={Test2456}}
\newglossaryentry{tc}{name=Test3, description={Test3789}}

% Use the terms
\gls{ta} is three hours behind \gls{tb} and 10 hours ahead of \gls{tc} blblbl.

%Print the glossary
\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

If I remove the `\glossaryentry` and reference, process the file, add the entry and reference and process (`pdflatex`, `makeglossaries` and `pdflatex`) the file again the updated entry is displayed in the list?

Is it something I am doing wrong (probably)... Or is theres something else? Anyone who can help me out?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 12):

By putting the `\newglossaryentry` before the `\begin{document}`, seems to solve the problem. Does this make sense?

```
\documentclass{article}

% Load the package
\usepackage{glossaries}

% Generate the glossary
\makeglossaries

%Term definitions
\newglossaryentry{ta}{name=Test1, description={Test123}}
\newglossaryentry{tb}{name=Test2, description={Test2456}}
\newglossaryentry{tc}{name=Test3, description={Test3789}}

\begin{document}

% Use the terms
\gls{ta} is three hours behind \gls{tb} and 10 hours ahead of \gls{tc} blblbl.

%Print the glossary
\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes it makes sense -- the package manual recommends `\newglossaryentry` in the preamble ;-)

Comment: Ok, thanks! I just started using Latex (one day) ans still have a lot to learn....

Comment: Why the downvote? This is the correct answer. The problem lies in the fact that definitions in the `document` environment are saved in a temporary file (`.glsdefs`) at the end of the document, which is then loaded at the start of the document in case `\printglossaries` is in the front matter. Modifications made to the definition aren't picked up until the temporary file is rewritten.